# Checking Page.IsPostBack in user controls

Tags: c#, asp.net, postback

Is it recommended to check the Page.IsPostBack in a user control Page_Load Event like

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        if (!Page.IsPostBack)
        {


        }


    }
```

I am getting wierd results

Edit ~ Here is the thing. When the main form is loaded, I use Request.QueryString to get the customer id which I then place in a SESSION variable.

On the control Load event I read the SESSION variable to get the data for that customer. So, do I need to check PostBack at the control level?

Edit ~ Here is the load event of the control

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!Page.IsPostBack)
        {
            //Getting and storing the customer account number 
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty((string)Session["CustomerNumber"]))
            {
                Session["CustomerNumber"] = cust.GetCustomerNumber(myHelper.GetCustomerIDFromQueryString());
                LoadProductData();
            }
        }

    }
```

Here is the myHelper Class

```
static class myHelper
{
    public static Guid GetCustomerIDFromQueryString()
    {
        //Getting the GUID (used as customerid in CRM) from the URL request of the selected account.  
        return Sql.ToGuid(System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request["ID"]);
    }

}
```

}

Comment: What "weird results" are you getting?

Comment: Sometimes I get data and sometimes not. If I remove the PostBack everything works fine. I edited my poost with exactly what I am doing.

Comment: Why do you have to place it in a session variable at all?  Why can't you just access the Request from your control?

Comment: Where in your sample code do you read the Request.QueryString? If it is in the if block or outside of it matters.

Comment: womp, I have several other controls on the page so instead of calling the Request several times I decided to call it once and put it in session.

Comment: MatthewMartin, I updated the post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use "!IsPostBack" in page load, when the user click other control it do a postBack, so you don't get your data.
 I hope that helps you.

Answer (score 0):

Just checking it for no reason? Absolutely not. If you should do something only on first load and not on subsequent post backs then it's the pattern that should be used.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that you will always have a "CustomerNumber" already stored in the Session by the time you get to your page?  Is there any rhyme or reason that you can find as to when you get data and when you don't?

Comment: Sometimes I get data and sometimes not. If I remove the PostBack everything works fine. I edited my poost with exactly what I am doing.